# Compass sprite and retina displays

Tags: sass, compass-sass, retina-display, sprite, css

I have generated a sprite with retina images using Compass, but would like to find a way of having the background positions match up with me using background-size: 100% on height/width half the size of the image. Is there a way I can manually make the background-positions cut in half so the positions are correct (since I am scaling down the image asset)?

Example of what I am trying to achieve with background-position:

http://www.studiopress.com/design/css-background-size-graphics.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for a while now without any problems :)

https://gist.github.com/Frexuz/fb8e9139f6ba18548f73

Place the normal icons in `images/sprites/icons`
Then make double sized icons and place them in `images/sprites/icons2x`

Important: The 2x needs to be exactly double sized, and the filename must match the corresponding 1x image :)